# what is integer equivalent of a date in SAP ABAP?

Tags: abap

How SAP was able to find out number of days from 00/00/0000 to a given date and name it as interger equivalent of particular date? Does it use any algorithm to return the same? I have got this doubt while using 'DATE_TO_DAY' function module.
Logic written in FM is as follows

```
    DATA: day_p TYPE p.
    day_p = date MOD 7.
    IF day_p > 1.
       day_p = day_p - 1.
    ELSE.
       day_p = day_p + 6.
    ENDIF.
```

Based on day_p value they are displaying 'Sunday', 'Monday', etc..
What exactly date MOD 7 returns is number of days from 00/00/0000 as specified above. So how does SAP achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Format the code properly and give the name of FM. Didn't get the idea too.

Comment: Please refer to the updated query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally SAP can interpret date type field as a number calculated by the rules of Gregorian calendar.

0 = 0000.00.00
1 = 0001.01.02

and so on ..

You can use arithmetic operators on these fields, for example compute elapsed days between two dates.

There's an SDN blog about this, [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2009/12/28/elegance-in-abap-date-calculations/).

More about the Gregorian calendar check [this](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) link and about weekday calculation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week). Check the tabular calculation method in this wiki article.